# Use Google Query to return results based on an Array

Tags: google-sheets, join, concatenation, google-query-language, textjoin

I have a function that queries an array, `material_items` and I want it to select all the rows where Column 1 matches another array `item_list_typeids`. Right now it only uses the first cell in the `item_list_typeids` in the query when there are currently 5 items in the array. That array is dynamic and there can be much more than just 5 items.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(
QUERY({material_items}, "select * WHERE Col1 = "&item_list_typeids&"",0),
""))
```

As you can see in the images below, there are multiple rows pulled for just the first item in the `item_list_typeids`, so the expected result will be over a dozen rows for just the 5 items in the array.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go for:

```
=IFNA(QUERY({material_items}, 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, item_list_typeids)&"'", 0))
```

Comment: That works, I just want to clarify something. The "|" acts as an "or" in google query language? Asking for future reference, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelJetzer yes, `|` stands for `OR` logic but in regex mode. we enabled regex mode with `matches`